# Cannot find module 'apollo-server' when deploying on AWS EC2 using docker-compose

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, node-modules, apollo-server

I have set up a GraphQL server and tried to deploy it on EC2 using docker-compose.
There is an error that "nodemon not found in npm". After adding "--global nodemon" in the Docker file, I ran docker-compose down, docker container prune, docker image rm [image name], then docker-compose up --build.

Then there is this Error: Cannot find module 'apollo-server'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFude.jpg)

docker-compose.yml

```js
version: '3.6'
services:

  graphql-server:
    container_name: backend
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - ./:/src/graphqlserver
    command: npm start
    working_dir: /src/graphqlserver
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
```

Dockerfile

```js
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /src/graphqlserver
WORKDIR /src/graphqlserver

COPY . /src/graphqlserver/

RUN npm install --global nodemon

EXPOSE 4000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

server.js

```js
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server');
const typeDefs = require('./typeDefs');
const resolvers = require('./resolvers');

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

package.json

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server": "^2.25.2",
    "graphql": "^15.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.9"
  }
```

Comment: The `volumes:` block hides everything interesting in the image, including the `node_modules` directory.  Delete that block from `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze! I added the volume block to keep track of changes in all of the folders. That way I don't need to rebuild everything whenever I add an api. Is there another way to do so? Thank you!

Comment: You could use Node directly for day-to-day development, even if you're eventually planning to deploy via Docker.

Comment: Also noting that you open the question with "...deploy it on EC2".  A typical Docker deployment scenario is to `docker build` an image with code built in and `docker push` it to some registry (in AWS, perhaps to ECR); then on the target system you can copy the `docker-compose.yml` file and run `docker-compose up`, without separately copying the application code.  The `volumes:` mean you also need to copy the application code, which negates an important Docker advantage here.

Comment: You could also just run `npm install` locally so your volume will contain your local `node_modules` folder